# ASEv2 - Front End & Workers - Billing

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

1. How many front-end pools come with an ASEv2 by default?
2. Are front-end pools included in the ASEv2 flat monthly fee? Are they charged based on number and level (I1, I2. I,3) along workers? i.e. 1x I1 Front-Ends + 1x I1 Worker = 2 I1 billable workers?

The MSFT documentation is not consistent on the above since the documentation I have acess to, mentions only 1 frontend by default (default level I1). Adding one I1 worker makes them 2 I1 for billable purposes. Am I right or just hallucinating?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.How many front-end pools come with an ASEv2 by default?

In ASEv2, when you scale out your App Service plans, workers are automatically added to support them. **Every ASE is created with two front ends**. In addition, the front ends automatically scale out at a rate of one front end for every 15 instances in your App Service plans. For example, if you have 15 instances, then you have three front ends. If you scale to 30 instances, then you have four front ends, and so on.

> Are front-end pools included in the ASEv2 flat monthly fee? Are they
> charged based on number and level (I1, I2. I,3) along workers? i.e. 1x
> I1 Front-Ends + 1x I1 Worker = 2 I1 billable workers?

First, we need to understand the difference between **Front ends** and **workers**

**Front ends:** The front ends are where HTTP/HTTPS terminates in an App Service environment (ASE).

**Workers:** The workers are the resources that host your apps.

So,Each App Service Environment incurs a monthly fee that **covers the Front Ends**.

The pricing is not like your example. The Tire which you have chosen  is an additional cost. The Worker is belong to your App service plan, not the ASE.
The following picture shows the pricing details:

[image]

As you consider, If you scale out your App and the instances will be added automatically. You don't need to pay for it when you reach added instances because it was added automatically.

Example: 1x I1 Front-Ends + 1x I1 Worker = 1 I1 billable worker

**Summary**

1.Each App Service Environment incurs a monthly fee that covers the Front Ends.

2.Workers is different from Front Ends, and you need to pay it additionally.
This price is based on how many and which Tier you're using in your App service plans.

3.Any instances which are added **automatically by scaling out** in ASE is free.

You can see more about Pricing of ASEv2 in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/using-an-ase#pricing).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer is pretty much what the documentation says. However, it does not seem to be accurate:

https://blog.mexia.com.au/when-to-use-an-app-service-environment-v2 mentions the default # of Front-Ends as being only ONE (1xI1). Which I have confirmed by actually implementing one ASEv2 environment. It looks like the monthly fee only covers the default 1xI1 Front-End worker. Upgrading Front-End worker tier incurrs a fee (seems like in line with worker tier pricing).

Feedback: documentation could be improved to match what you actually find while implementing an ASEv2 based solution.